# Ionic how to execute code after reading and saving data from SQLite

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have this code:

```
this.db.executeSql('SELECT * FROM visit', [])
.then(res =>{
  var payload = [];
  var visit_payload = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++){
    visit_payload = {
      id: res.rows.item(i).uid,
      visit_date: res.rows.item(i).visit_date,
      user_uid: res.rows.item(i).user_uid,
      visit_sig: res.rows.item(i).visit_sig
    }
    this.db.executeSql('SELECT field_uid, data, report_order FROM visit_info WHERE visit_uid = ?', [visit_payload['id']])
    .then(res2 => {
      var visit_data_payload = [];
      for (var j = 0; j < res2.rows.length; j++){
        visit_data_payload.push({
          field_uid: res2.rows.item(j).field_uid,
          data: res2.rows.item(j).data,
          report_order: res2.rows.item(j).report_order
        });
        visit_payload['data'] = visit_data_payload;
      }
      payload.push(visit_payload);
      console.log(payload);
    })
  } //point 
});
```

I need to execute a code after reading all of the data from those SELECT statements. I tried doing it below where it says `//point`, which is where the first loop ends. The problem is, my payload is empty when I `console.log()` it. I am assuming this is because of the whole asynchrony thing. I tried doing my code where the `console.log(payload)` is right now, but the problem is that the code is executed as many times as the first loop runs. And I need it to run only once. Is there any way I can do my code after all of the SELECT, after having obtained all of my data?

Also any suggestions to make the code better are welcome. This is my first time working in Ionic and I am learning everything from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO and Ionic!
Looks like your question is how you can run one SQLite query and then populate your payload, instead of running one query against 'visit' table and then run another query for every row in the result.

At least one soultion is using SQL's

> Inner Join

command
http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-inner-join/

this way you would only run one query which will JOIN the two tables.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! If I did a JOIN, I would have to check for when the visit id's change, so I can create a new object with the other visit's data. The way the tables are set up is that in visit I have the ID and some other information, and in visit_info there are multiple rows for one visit id.